# an WSO2 Integration Studio project be can migrate to Enterprise Integrator 7.1.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I was taking an WSO2 ESB course for do integration and make a enterprise service buses and i developed an REST service in Integration Studio 8.0 tool by WSO2 . I believe have understanted that for put into production an WSO2 Integration Studio project i must put my project in WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 7.1.0, is correctly this afirmation?.

i developed an REST data service for execute a stored procedure in a MySQL database manager using WSO2 Integration Studio and each time that i need execute it obviusly must open mi Integration Studio IDE and do an "Export Project Articats and Run" in my project.

Then for not depende of the Integration Studio IDE i must export my project to Enterprise Integrator??
I am beginner in WSO2 and just dominate Integration Studio tool, i only need 2 kicks to understand complet this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either export your integration as a Carbon Application as explained [here](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/packaging-artifacts/#creating-a-new-composite-application) and deploy it to MI/EI runtime by copying it to `EI_HOME/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps` directory. Else you can create a Docker image with the integration and run it as described [here](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/create-docker-project/).

Comment: ok, complety understable, i can get it thanks to you, thanks